# Cannot resolve symbol R in copied project

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I am making an Android app. Due to some reasons, my current project files got all messed up. To solve this issue I created a new project in Android Studio and copied the files from the previous project to this new project.

I carefully copied all the **layout, values, java** files at their right location. I replaced the relevant content from the new manifest and Gradle files with new content.

Everything looked perfect and then I got the "Cannot resolve symbol R" error.

I tried all the solutions like **Invalidate Cache/Restart, Sync files with gradle, Rebuild Project, Clean Project etc. etc. etc.**

Still couldn't fix it.

Can someone help?

Problem Details

1. I have correct package name everywhere (in AndroidManifest too)
2. I have proper and valid xml files
3. Even if I copied the files from other project the I've kept the project name and package names exactly the same.
4. I have only one app module.

Comment: Something's failing during the resource build. Look carefully through everything under the `res/` folder to check for any files that might have errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .R line from every java class .

Comment: I've not imported R anywhere. Even if I try to import it shows the same error.

Comment: then there must be a problem with your package name on java class , as these are copied from other projects with other's package name .

Answer (score 0):

You might have an error in one of your `xml` files, like a duplicated `xml` header. Check for every single one.

You can also update Android Studio as it now tells you the file and location of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you copy and paste your codes to individual right places if you want to move these to a new project. Copying folders and files to a newly created project would not work as there could be some lines that include your old folder paths

For example, your old project was in `C://StudioProjects/YourProjectName` so your codes should be in `C://StudioProjects/YourProjectName/app/src/main/java/com/example/AppName` but if you directly copy a file or folder to a newly created project, you could end up referencing the wrong path like `C://StudioProjects/YourProjectName/app/src/main/java/com/example/NewAppName` and this could blow your XML file which will lead to R cannot resolve symbol R.

Even though you put your folders in the same path, reference numbers changed in the new project.